# Converting Vanilla JS to Vue.js, querySelector, this issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to convert this CodePen: https://codepen.io/kjbrum/pen/qooQJJ to Vue.js component.

I added `this.$nextTick` to handle DOM but still unable to get this working.

I created CodeSandbox with the code mostly implemented:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shape-httqv?file=/src/components/cursor-dot/CursorDot.vue

I feel this is an issue with `this` getting confused. I will appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: you're right. you're using `this.` instead of `cursor.` in some places, and also, `this` is probably not what you expect when you use arrow functions

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

@Jaromanda X actually answered my issue. `this` in arrow functions gives mixed results.